Why is not obvious that if $A$ is a set, then $|A| < |P(A)|$
It is well known that $|A| < |P(A)|$
I have seen Cantors Proof for this. But I do have a naive question : If $A$ has $n$ elements, then $P(A)$ has $2^n$ elements. Therefore isn't it obvious that $|A| < |P(A)|$? Why we should even consider that tautology ?

The issue lies with sets that might have infinite elements. The theorem is true, even for them.

oh!! right. Did not think of it. Thank you

Proof is required because it is not actually obvious , while we have more such obvious cases where our intuition goes wrong.
Think about these "Numbers" , where $N$ is the Cardinality of Natural Numbers :
$$N,N+2,N+8,2N,8N,N^2,N^8,2^N,8^N,N^N$$
Does your intuition say that we can "obviously" put $\lt$ between each Pair ?
Well , we actually have to put $=$ for the first $7$ "Numbers".
What about the last $3$ "Numbers" ?
Well , here is the "Ordering" :
$$N = N+2 = N+8 = 2N = 8N = N^2 = N^8 \lt 2^N = 8^N = N^N$$
I will leave you with this to think over :
$$2^{2^N} \gt 2^N \gt N\gt 1 \gt 0$$
Some of that is obvious. Some of that is hardly obvious.

In a sense it depends on what you mean by “obvious”.  Do you think that $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{Q}|$ is an “obviously” true statement? After all, amongst the rational numbers of the form $p/q$, for each (positive) denominator $q$ there are infinitely many possible numerators $p$. But in reality it is not a true statement: there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the natural numbers and rational numbers, and so they have the same cardinality.
The key insight of Cantor’s 1874 paper was that that there cannot exist any 1-to-1 mapping between the natural numbers and real numbers, that $\mathbb{R}$ is an unquestionably bigger kind of infinity than $\mathbb{N}$ (hence $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{R}|$). This idea of some infinities being bigger than other infinities was not at all obvious to people in 1874.
